How to approximate the integral $\int^{\infty}_0 x^{2a}\cos{(c_0 x^a)}\exp{(- c_1 x^{2a} - x)} dx$
For the integral
$$
\int^{\infty}_{0}x^{2a}\cos\left(c_{0}x^{a}\right)
\exp\left(-c_{1}x^{2a} - x\right)\,{\rm d}x
$$
that is too complicated to obtain a closed-form result.

Is it possible to approximate it or find an upper bound for it analytically ?.

Any help is appreciated.
UPDATES: $a$ is a negative small value.

For small $a$ integrating the terms of a series expansion gives a value $\cos c_0 e^{-c_1} + \gamma e^{-c_1}(c_0 \sin c_0 + 2 (c_1 - 1) \cos c_0) + R(a)$, $R(a) \in O(a^2)$, where $\gamma is the Euler–Mascheroni constant. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euler%27s_constant Assuming $c_1 < 0$ (which is necessary for convergence), we get the cheap but not particularly robust upper bound $\Gamma(2 a + 1)$, which is uniform in $c_0, c_1$.

Is it for small $a$ or large $a$? Separately if you're trying to take a limit in $a$ that would be easier to do directly as well.

@NinadMunshi Thanks for pointing it out, I have clarified the range of a

@TravisWillse Thank you! I have trouble obtaining your first formula. Did you expand the exponential function as a series and integrate each term along with $x^{2a}$ and $cos(c_0x^a)$?

Expand in a Taylor series in a, then integrate each term separately. The second term in the expansion is missing an $a$ in my previous comment.
